# How to call Form from another solution's project

Tags: c#, windows

For example, I've got `Solution1` with WinFormProject1 and simple `Form1` with one `Open` button, and I want when this button is clicked , to open `Solution2` WinFormProject2 `Form1`.

How can I accomplish this ? 
Thank you!

Comment: keep 2 projects in the same solution

Comment: :D I want them in different solution ;)

Comment: You need to reference Solution2->Project in Solution1->Project. You can then use it just like it were in two projects in the same solution, just be aware of how easy it can be for these to get out of sync.

Comment: Do you want that say `Form1` and `Form2` communicate and keep their source code separate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Assembly containing `Form1` from `Solution2` as an external Reference in the `WinFormProject1`, as Ron Beyer said.

The assembly will be **copied** to the directory of `WinFormProject1` and you will be able to use `WinFormProject2.Form1` from your code. Note that since it will be copied there will be no synchronization between the two solutions, and you will need to manually update the copy of the Assembly containing `WinFormProject2.Form1` into `Solution1`, if needed.

There is no way of doing that while keeping the two in sync **and** in two separate solutions, you must choose one or the other.